# jQuery script not working on IE correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a strange issue with Internet Explorer, i wrote a navigation code and it's working perfectly on Chrome and FF, and it's half working in IE (Don't know how). So here is my issue

When i hover on the link is opens a mega menu down and remove the border-right of the current anchor and the previous one. (See picture below)

[image: http://s11.postimage.org/7vwtigsxv/nav.png]

And this is how is looks when i hover on the link (I managed to make it work on all browsers: Chrome, FF, Safari and IE 6-9

[image: http://s11.postimage.org/9c8c0lvur/nav_hover.png]

The issue comes here when i hover out of the link, if i hover up, the borders will come back without any issues but when i hover out downward, the border-right of the previous link doesn't come back (See below pic)

I will include the third picture on a comment as i can't post more than 2 links.

This is the code i wrote in jQuery

```
$(".menu li").hover(
  function () {
    var result = $(this).index();           
    var item = $('a.mainnav')[result - 1];

    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).find('a.mainnav').css('border-right','none');
    $(this).parent().find(item).css('border-right','none');
  },
  function () {
    var result = $(this).index();           
    var item = $('a.mainnav')[result - 1];

    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(this).find('a.mainnav').css('border-right','1px solid #000');
    $(this).parent().find(item).css('border-right','1px solid #000');
  }
);
```

anyone know why this issue is happening?

p.s. Sorry that i can't post the pictures directly because i'm new.

Comment: That's the third Image:
http://s11.postimage.org/50jqbloxv/nav_out_down.png

Comment: Is it impossible to do this in CSS? And Why?

Comment: @VainFellowman because if i use CSS3, it won't work on IE as it doesn't support nth-child()

Comment: Do you have an example of why you need nth-child? Including some markup?

Comment: @VainFellowman for targeting the prev li you need to use jQuery not CSS, and prev() doesn't work on IE6-8 that's why i'm getting the index and making - 1

Comment: could you please post the corresponding markup? There might be a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code somewhat. When leaving hover state; Is it okay for you to remove border-right style from all `a.mainnav` elements? They will go back to your CSS definition.

```
$(".menu li").hover(
  function () {         
    var item = $('a.mainnav')[$(this).index() - 1];

    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $(this).find('a.mainnav').css('border-right','none');
    item.css('border-right','none');
  },
  function () {    
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $(item).find('a.mainnav').css('border-right','');
  }
);
```